# Facebook 'User opted out of platform' Error When User Tries To Share To Business Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My application has a Facebook Share button that, up until recently, worked fine via the Facebook Graph API.

When a user tries to share to their business page, it seems to display the following error:

'User opted out of platform: The action attempted is disallowed, because the user has opted out of Facebook platform.'

Opted Out Error Screenshot

[image: 1]

They are able to share just fine if logged into their personal page but when logged into a business page it fails with the above error.

We use Facebook's Business Integration Feature to allow our business to manage their pages.

When navigating to **Settings & Privacy > Settings > Security and Login > Business Integrations** on Facebook logged in as a personal user with management access (this does not exists when logged in as a page), all permission seem to be enabled.

Has anyone run into this issue and found any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that your settings are preventing other platforms from interacting with your account. To solve it you have enable "**Apps, Websites & Plugins**" from settings. If they are enabled and its still not working there will be a further sub-option of **"Enable Platform"**.

Answer (score 2):

What I did (June 2023) was, in the Facebook account that the app is registered under, go to `Me (upper right hand corner icon) > Settings > Apps and Websites`, then `disable` and then `reenable` both `Apps, websites and games` and `Game and app notifications`. Not sure if both were necessary.